# Module Not Found Error - Python 3. Works fine in SHELL but not from a file

Tags: python-3.x, module, pip

I'm running Python 3.6.4 and have been pip-installing modules and working with them just fine until today. For some reason, after I installed the module and tried running some sample code, I get this error:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bokeh.plotting'; 'bokeh' is not a package
```

However, it works perfectly fine when I type it in line by line in the Python Shell! Blows my mind. I've tried different IDE's, from IDLE to ATOM to SPYDER to running off the CMD line. I've checked the install directory and I see the package installed there.

Here is the code. Again, it works perfectly fine in the SHELL, but not when saved in any .PY file.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
output_file("test.html")
p = figure()
p.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=2)
show(p)
```

Comment: Most probably you have 2 or more Pythons, and run the code interactively with 1 of them while scripts use another.

Comment: thanks for your response. i was only running python 3.6.4 --- am installing python 3.7 now and seeing if that will make a difference.

Comment: More strange stuff happening - when I move the .py file to different folders, the import module function works. Sometimes, when I create a new .py file from scratch and paste the import module, it will work, sometimes it doesn't. Truly baffling!